# How to prevent WebRequest Conflicts between Multi Methods in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

'm new here so please bear with me. Happy to clarify if any questions/clarification.

In all my processes I have LogHandler method via WebRequest which basically store what process was called by user and this runs as Thread so existing processes are not slowed down.

I have another method called StatusCheckX which basically does another WebRequest and check if data needed exist and perform certain task with the data.

**Problem I'm facing** is that of WebRequest from StatusCheckX and LogHandler seems to be conflicting/waiting on another and stops responding and eventually times out. How can I overcome this.

Thanks for help/advice.
Ari.

```
Public Function Important_Method1() As Boolean

    Dim VariableX As Boolean = True

    Try
        'do something
        'do something
        
        Call LogHandler()
        
        If VariableX = True Then
            If StatusCheckX() = False Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End If

        

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

    End Try


End Function

Public Function Important_Method2() As Boolean

    Dim VariableX As Boolean = True

    Try
        'do something
        'do something
        
        Call LogHandler()
        
        If VariableX = True Then
            If StatusCheckX() = False Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End If

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

    End Try


End Function


Private Function LogHandler() As Boolean

    Dim T1 As Thread
    T1 = New Thread(AddressOf WriteLogX)
    T1.Start()

    Return True

End Function

Private Function WriteLogX() As Boolean
    Dim url As String = "www.xyz.com"
    Try
        Dim Req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim Res As HttpWebResponse = CType(Req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If Res.StatusDescription = "ALL GOOD" Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

        Res.Close()
        Res.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Private Function StatusCheckX() As Boolean
    Try

        'do something
        'do something
        'do something

        Dim Req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("www.ijk.com")
        Dim Res As HttpWebResponse = CType(Req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If Res.StatusDescription = "OK" Then
            Dim ResStream As System.IO.Stream = Res.GetResponseStream()
            Dim SReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(ResStream)
            Dim i As String = SReader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(i)

            SReader.Close()
            SReader.Dispose()

            ResStream.Close()
            ResStream.Dispose()

            If dict.Values(0) = "OK PROCEED" Then
                'do something
                Return True
            Else
                'do something
                Return False
            End If

        Else
            Return False

        End If

        Res.Close()
        Res.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: hoping someone can assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it helps anyone, I finally moved it to new class and error went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).